# Make a wp_remote_post when not logged in

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, curl, woocommerce

Hi i'm developing a plugin which adds a new field to the order (WooCommerce). The field needs to make an ajax request to a file in my plugin, that file then needs to make a cURL request to another website (or wp_remote_post). But i'm experiencing difficulties when making the request.

I can't get the ordinary cURL to work nor the wp_remote_post function.

Here's a snippet of the cURL in my file which the ajax requests to.

```
<?php

$shipping_place = array(
                'country_code' => $country_code,
                'postcode' => $postcode,
                'street' => $street,
                'number_of_droppoints' => $number_of_droppoints
            );

            $auth = array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode('user:password')
            );

            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $auth);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $shipping_place);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            if(curl_errno($ch)){
                $msg = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
            } else {
                $result = json_decode($result['body']);

                if ( $result->status == 'error' ) {
                    echo $result;
                }

                pred($result);

                echo $result->result;
            }

            curl_close ($ch);
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I had to localize the wp-admin script.

That would use the wp function like this

```
<?php wp_localize_script( $handle, $name, $data ); ?>
```

Reference [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

Comment: Any further detail or snippet of code to share in your answer? Would make it helpful to others.

Comment: Of course here's a link: [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)